# How to use automatic text binding with checkbox SWT button

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm using JFace databinding framework to link checkbox selection with model:

```java
final DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();
final Realm realm = ctx.getValidationRealm();
final IViewerObservableValue selection = ViewersObservables.observeSingleSelection(viewer);
final IObservableValue selectionObservable = BeansObservables.observeDetailValue(realm, selection, "isSelected", boolean.class);
final UpdateValueStrategy strategy = new UpdateValueStrategy(true, UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_UPDATE);
ctx.bindValue(SWTObservables.observeSelection(button), selectionObservable, strategy, strategy);
```

The presentation needs to use the checkbox's text to display specific information about the current selection, but it's not possible to use `observeText(Control)`:

```java
final UpdateValueStrategy update = new UpdateValueStrategy(true, UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_NEVER);
ctx.bindValue(SWTObservables.observeText(button), textObservable, null, update);
```

It causes an SWTException:

> *Could not create the view: Widget [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button] is not supported.*

Is there a way to do text binding on SWT Button ?

### EDIT

The fast solution is to put a Label next the checkbox, then the binding could be done easily with `SWTObservables.observeText(label)`

### SOLUTION

It works on eclipse 3.7

Comment: Works for me. Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: @Tonny Madsen I'm using Eclipse 3.4

Comment: Eclipse 3.4 - Hmm, that was the first version of Eclipse Databinding. I cannot test the capabilities of 3.4 unless I make a new installation of it... If at all possible, consider moving to a newer version :-)

Comment: @Tonny Madsen This topic is currently being discussed ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK. From what I understand, the user selects a button, the selection is transferred to the Model, and then you want the Button to show some new text. If that's the case, here is the solution:

```
DataBindingContext dbc = getBindingContext();
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button b = null; // New with the proper flag for CHECK
Object theModelBean = null;  // Initialize as you wish
```

Now, You need TWO bindings. The first Binding, Binds the selection to a boolean in the model:

```
ISWTObservableValue targetBool = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(b);
IObservableValue modelBool = BeanProperties.value("someBooleanField").observe(theModelBean);
dbc.bindValue(targetBool, modelBool);
```

Now, when the selection occurs, the "setSomeBooleanField" method is called on the model Object. In order to also change the Text of the Button, this setter MUST call another setter on your model Object setting the new "text" that you want to be shown. This second setter fires a Property Change event which in turn wakes up your second binding which is:

```
IObservableValue targetText = BeanProperties.value("text").observe(b);
IObservableValue modelText = BeanProperties.value("theTextInTheBean").observe(theModelBean);
dbc.bindValue(targetText, modelText);
```

This binding is going to work only from model to target, so you can set thje targetToModel policy to NEVER.

You see, the "text" field of button is not supported by ViewerProperties, but it is Supported by WidgetProperties and also the BeanProperties class. You can Bind Pretty much ANYTHING with BeanProperties as long as the setter fires a Property Change Event.

The setters in the model must be like this:

```
public void setSomeBooleanField(boolean b){
    firePropertyChange("someBooleanField", this.someBooleanField, this.someBooleanField = b);
    // Form the new Text
    this.setNewText(newText);
}

public void setNewText(String newText){
    firePropertyChange("newText", this.newText, this.newText = newText); // Wake up the second Binding
}
```

Comment: Of course, for the second binding to work, you don't need to actually bind it to a String, you can bind it to any thing, as long as you provide the proper IConverters for the second Binding, and you wake it up by firing a Property Change event.